# Check if "data" contain items of Array

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular-route-guards

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.securityService.securityActions().subscribe(
            data => {debugger;
            if(data = this.authorized.find(k => k=='AGREEMENTS_VIEW','AGREEMENTS_INSERT_UPDATE')){
                resolve(true);    
            }
                if(data != this.authorized){
                   resolve(false);
                }
            },
            error => {
                Utils.notifyErrors(error, this.notificationsService);

            }
        )
    });
}
```

I want to set true if data contains some items of "authorized".

Authorized is formed like this:

```
  authorized = [
        'AGREEMENTS_VIEW',
        'PROSPECTS_VIEW',
        'AGREEMENTS_INSERT_UPDATE',
        'PRODUCTS_INSERT_UPDATE',
        'PROSPECTS_INSERT_UPDATE',
        'DOCUMENTS_VIEW',
        'DOCUMENTS_INSERT_UPDATE',
    ];
```

So for example set true if data contains 'AGREEMENTS_VIEW'.

Right now if i set 2 value on K it doesnt work

Comment: That syntax makes no sense, you're passing `'AGREEMENTS_INSERT_UPDATE'` as a second argument to `.find`. This doesn't seem to be a route guard, Angular or even TypeScript problem; you need to clarify what your precise logic for comparing the two arrays (right?) is.

Comment: Also please stop using random quote formatting in your posts; use that *when you're quoting something*.

Comment: yeah i was trying to find a way to add 2 arguments on .find(). Is that possible? and also, even with 1 "k" says illegal return statement

Comment: **What is the logic?** I suspect that if you could clearly describe the logic in the question, you would be a long way towards explaining it to JavaScript, too. Please give a proper [mcve] and clear context, or you'll just keep asking the same question [over](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51818528/3001761) and [over](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51816933/3001761) and [over](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51767935/3001761) again.

Comment: yeah they were from a previous thing i did there, ive removed them

Answer (score 0):

Use `some`, which returns true if the condition is matched.

```
return arrayOne.some(itemOfArrayOne => arrayTwo.includes(itemOfArrayOne));
```

You can replace `includes` with `indexOf(XXX) !== -1`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a syntax error:

```
data === this.authorized.find(k => k=='AGREEMENTS_VIEW')
//---^^^-----here
```

Comment: yeah you are right, ive found another problem. K in debug says Illegal return statement

Comment: Yes! that is illegal. as you are comparing k with two values. you can use `||` operateor

Comment: well it says the same even with 1 argument